# Web server serving HTML page instead of JSON 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to retrieve the JSON from http://www.bartdekimpe.be/anoire/index.php/admin/getGamesUserJson/34 but I can't seem to get it working. I can get it but then I get the hole html page

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.bartdekimpe.be/anoire/index.php/admin/getGamesUserJson/34',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".testing").append(data);
    }
});
```

That works, but as I said, I got the whole HTML page. And when I put it in a variable like this:

```
downloadedjson = data;
$(".testing").append(downloadedjson);
```

That last one doesn't work. I want to put it in a variable so I can write a file later on my iPhone.

Comment: Please post your full AJAX request code.

Comment: That page you linked to does not return JSON, it returns a plain text HTML document. Also if your server-side script returns JSON you will have to iterate through it, you can't just append it to the DOM: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not treating this as JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.bartdekimpe.be/anoire/index.php/admin/getGamesUserJson/34',
    dataType: 'json', <--- you'll need this
    success: function(data) {
        $(".testing").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that jQuery has a [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) shortcut method that will do this automagically.

Comment: I tried the .getJSON() it didn't work. And when I add "dataType: 'json'" It doesn't work eather, without it it does

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you are returning JSON as a plain text HTML document. You change this in the HTTP headers. It looks like you are using PHP so this is the code that you need to place in your php before any output occurs.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename="gamesUser.json");
```

I not sure if the second line is 100% needed, but I usually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is rendering text/html HTTP response, not JSON response.

You are outputting HTML code, not JSON data.

This is an issue of your web server technology and not related to Phonegap. However your question is inaccurate and you do not clarify how you are serving JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was adding header and footer in my PHP page that is actually not needed. it should be a pure PHP page that starts and ends with PHP tags and that is it ( no extra CSS or JS linked file or code )